# Backintime won't start (no module named dbus)

Tags: 14.04, python, dependencies, dbus, backintime

I've got the following error on Ubunu 14.04 :

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo backintime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/backintime/common/backintime.py", line 26, in 
    import config
  File "/usr/share/backintime/common/config.py", line 30, in 
    import tools
  File "/usr/share/backintime/common/tools.py", line 27, in 
    import dbus
ImportError: No module named dbus
```

I've already tried to [install/uninstall python-secretstorage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/backintime/+bug/1245134), but it seems it doesn't change anything ...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some dependencies. Please install them with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dbus python3-dbus.mainloop.qt
```

---

Using `sudo backintime` causes some troubles because of wrong `$HOME`. Please use either `sudo -i backintime` for command-line or `gksudo backintime-gnome` for the old Gnome GUI or `pkexec backintime-qt4` for the new Qt4 GUI instead.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT-Dev Team</sub>